# query select if id two digits or three digits

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a query  if st.style_perm_id is two digit leave it as is and if three digit then display three digit.

Here is the part of the query I need to update

```
 SELECT
st.style_id
, decode(greatest(max(sd.sub_division_perm_id),99)
         , 99, to_number(LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(sd.model_year), '9999'))
                         || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(sd.sub_division_perm_id), '09'))
                         || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(ymm.model_perm_id), '09'))
                         || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(st.style_perm_id), '09')))

         , null) hist_style_id
, 'w' || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(sd.model_year), '9999'))
   || 'k' || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(sd.sub_division_perm_id), '999'))
   || 'm' || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(ymm.model_perm_id), '999'))
   || 't' || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(st.style_perm_id), '999')) style_token
, max(sd.model_year) model_year
```

I tried using a case

```
  SELECT
st.style_id
, decode(greatest(max(sd.sub_division_perm_id),99)
         , 99, to_number(LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(sd.model_year), '9999'))
                         || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(sd.sub_division_perm_id), '09'))
                         || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(ymm.model_perm_id), '09'))
                         || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(st.style_perm_id), '09'))
                         || CASE WHEN st.style_perm_id < 99 THEN LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(st.style_perm_id), '99'))
                          WHEN st.style_perm_id < 999 THEN LTRIM(TO_CHAR(max(st.style_perm_id), '999')))
                        END
```

I get the error as below.

> ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Im not sure if that's the right approach.

How can I update a query if `st.style_perm_id` is two digit leave it as is and if three digit then display three digit.

Thankis for your help as I am banging my head for hours.

Comment: "I am trying to update a query if `st.style_perm_id` is two digit leave it as is and if three digit then display three digit."  This is why sample data is so helpful in conveying what one really wants.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff, sample data is needed to help with requirements. But for syntax, I can say that your `END` needs to be inside of the parenthesis for `TO_NUMBER`. Currently, you end three calls on the second to last time, but the END should be inside of the final.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot remember when I last saw decode in use, and don't think I've ever used it in my code, but the following small test shows both a case expression and a decode for your situation.

```
with st as ( 
    select 98 as style_perm_id from dual union all
    select 798 from dual
    )
select
  max(st.style_perm_id) MAXVALUE
, CASE WHEN max(st.style_perm_id) < 99 THEN ltrim(to_char(max(st.style_perm_id), '99')) 
       WHEN max(st.style_perm_id) < 999 THEN ltrim(to_char(max(st.style_perm_id), '999')) 
       ELSE ' ' 
       END   BY_CASE   
, DECODE(sign(999-max(st.style_perm_id)), 1,ltrim(to_char(max(st.style_perm_id), '999')),
  DECODE(sign(99-max(st.style_perm_id)), 1,ltrim(to_char(max(st.style_perm_id), '99'))),' ')   BY_DECODE
from st
```

[I used an asktom discussion](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:4333097088785) to assist with the decode, which is where the sign(...) comes from